# Ajax success not reading PHP echo as string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple PHP script which, when it executes correctly from an AJAX call, ends with:

```
echo "ok";
```

Yet when I try to parse this information it tells me its not a string.

In the example below the result is: `alert('error: Type Mismatch');`

Why does JQuery not read the php echo as a string?

```
$.ajax({
url: '/ajax/actions/imageUpload.php?act_id=<?=$act_id?>',
type: 'POST',
success: function (response) {
    if(typeof response == typeof 'string'){
        if( response == 'ok')
             alert('all is good');
         else
           alert('error:');
    } else {
        alert('error: Type Mismatch');
    }
}
});
```

Screenshot below shows that the response is correct and simply says 'ok'

[image]

Comment: post your `imageUpload.php`, as this simply means you are not hitting the intended file/function

Comment: @noobie-php Amended question to show that response is correct

Comment: What appear if you alert the **response** itself?

Comment: If I `alert(response);` I get a pop up simply saying 'ok', as it should

Comment: What's the result of `console.info(typeof response);`? after `success: function (response) {`

Comment: @ilpaijin `object` - good call, why is that?

Comment: Hmm you should get "string" and not "object". I get object if I `echo json_encode(array("ok"));` from `imageUpload.php` and then if I set `dataType: "json"` as a $.ajax object param

Comment: @Darren Sweeney I'm just reading from jquery Api doc: "DataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

As I'm reading from jquery Api Doc I understand that you can get a "string" or something else as a `response`, based on what kind of dataType you passed (if u did) in your $.ajax object. Otherwise it will be assumpted from jQuery, based on some its own logic.

In my opinion you should avoid every assumption and explicitly pass your dataType based on the response format you'll send.

So,

in case you'll set `response.php` to return

```
echo "ok";
```

you should set dataType "text" in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'imageUpload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "text",
    ...
```

and get the response with:

```
if(typeof response == "string")
{
    console.info(response);
    ...
```

Or

in case you'll set `response.php` to return something like

```
echo json_encode(array("data" => "ok"));
```

you should set dataType "json":

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'imageUpload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    ...
```

and get the response with:

```
if(typeof response == "object")
{
    console.info(response.data);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: '/ajax/actions/imageUpload.php?act_id=<?=$act_id?>',
type: 'POST',
success: function (response) {
        if (typeof response === "string"){
            if (response == 'ok')
                alert('all is good');
            else
                alert('error:');
        } else {
            alert('error: Type Mismatch');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer anything about why the PHP echo is not being read as a string

Answer (score 0):

Do it another way:

In you php script echo back a JSON: `json_encode("ok");`

In AJAX specify `dataType: "json"` and add event:

```
complete: function(jsondata, stat)
{
  if(stat == "success")
      alert( $.parseJSON( jsondata.responseText ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is not string type, it is a PlainObject object.

```
success
Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )


typeof response == 'object' // true
```

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/actions/imageUpload.php?act_id=<?=$act_id?>',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "text", 
    success: function (response) {

        if( response == 'ok')
             alert('all is good');
        else
           alert('error:');
    }
});
```